# is there any sql command to retrieve data

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am learning `SQL` using `MySQL` workbench.

Unfortunately I have lost all my performed queries and commands by mistakenly pressing control z commands.

Is there any command to get back my all written queries or how can i see the history?

I have tried all the undo commands, but none of them worked

Comment: Select queries, or what type of queries? Perhaps transaction logs, if you had those turned on and are looking for modification queries.

Comment: You should try to see on the workbench if selecting "Load saved/last query" bring back the query you're looking for. If that doesn't work, those queries are likely lost forever.

Comment: You can find a log of the History from the Mysql Workbench in your Appdata Folder:

```(%AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\) ```
or 

```C:\Users\[YourUsername]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_history```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CTRL+Z is undo and that deleted your work, have you tried CTRL+Y to redo it?

More Shortcuts:
http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html

Comment: Presumably the OP has done some action after running the undo. As they state `how can i see the history?`. So CTRL+Y does not sound like a solution for that.